# PHP dynamic select box using $_POST?

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I was wondering if there is a way similar to the code below in order to use 'conditional' select boxes. I tried a few jquery methods, but I really got stuck since I use wordpress, and this should be a search box so it complicates things for me.

```
<form name="main" method="post">
  <select name="currency-select">
    <option value="default">Currency</option> 
    <option value="a">U.S Dollars (USD)</option> 
    <option value="b">Euros (EUR)</option> 
    <option value="c">British Pounds (GBP)</option> 
  </select>
</form>

<form name="child">
  <select name="currency-child">

    <?php if($_POST['currency-select'] == "a"): >
      <option value="1">price</option> 
      <option value="2">100</option> 
      <option value="3">200</option> 
      <option value="4">300</option> 
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($_POST['currency-select'] == "b"): >
      <option value="5">price</option> 
      <option value="6">50</option> 
      <option value="7">60</option> 
      <option value="8">70</option> 
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($_POST['currency-select'] == "c"): >
      <option value="9">price</option> 
      <option value="10">130</option> 
      <option value="11">260</option> 
      <option value="12">390</option> 
    <?php endif; ?>

  </select>
</form>
```

Update : syntax errors fixed

Comment: Are those two on the same page? If so, then the `$_POST` doesn't make sense because you'd have to send the form first to render the second part. Of course you can do it with JavaScript (or jQuery if necessary). Just show the proper `<option>` elements depending on which option is chosen in the first select.

Comment: Are you sure there are no syntax errors in there?

Comment: If this is as complicated as it gets, I would just add 3 `select` boxes and only show the one that applies based on the selection of the `currency-select` box. If it gets more complicated, you'd have to use ajax.

Comment: Yeah they are on the same page, so I guess really the '$_POST' method would not help here right?

Is there a way to do it without ajax/js? It's really as complicated as it gets. 1 parent box and 3 child boxes.

There could be syntax errors, I didn't try the code, as I just wanted to know if this idea is anyhow possible to execute.

Comment: Also <option value="a"U.S Dollars (USD)</option> - You forget to close the opening option tag

Comment: That should be easy, add 3 complete `currency-child` select boxes, hide them and show the one that applies based on the currency selection. What have you tried with jQuery exactly?

Comment: How should I hide/show them based on the selection? I tried to use this [guide](http://webomnizz.com/blog/php/dynamic-select-box-with-jquery-and-php/) , but it's a bit complicated to use with the current way the search form is working..

Comment: Hi guys, I got it using js finally. just showing and hiding the other fields each time as you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the form is not submited, PHP don't do any thing about your form, and you don't have a submit button in your html so the values won't be set in your PHP script.
I suggest you `jQuery`.
I wrote the **code** below for you, but you have to set the new attributes for your html elements and append a `<div>` with `id="wrapper"`--> `<div id="wrapper">`
If you didn't append `wrapper`, change `$('#wrapper').on('change', 'form#main', function() {` with`$(document).on('change', 'form#main', function() {`.
but in larg codes, I suggest `#wrapper` instead of `document`.

**CODE:**
**Add this lines in the `<head>` of page:**

```
//jQuery
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#wrapper').on('change', 'form#main', function() {
            if ( $('#a').is(':selected') ) {
                $('option.remove').remove();
                $('#child1').append('<option value="1" class="remove">price</option>');
                $('#child1').append('<option value="2" class="remove">100</option>');
                $('#child1').append('<option value="3" class="remove">200</option>');
                $('#child1').append('<option value="4" class="remove">300</option>');

            }
            else if ( $('#b').is(':selected') ) {
                $('option.remove').remove();
                $('#child1').append('<option value="1" class="remove">price</option>');
                $('#child1').append('<option value="6" class="remove">50</option>');
                $('#child1').append('<option value="7" class="remove">60</option>');
                $('#child1').append('<option value="8" class="remove">70</option>');
            }
            else if ( $('#c').is(':selected') ) {
                $('option.remove').remove();
                $('#child1').append('<option value="9" class="remove">price</option>');
                $('#child1').append('<option value="10" class="remove">130</option>');
                $('#child1').append('<option value="11" class="remove">260</option>');
                $('#child1').append('<option value="12" class="remove">390</option>');

            }
            else if ( $('#default').is(':selected') ) {
                $('option.remove').remove();//reset every thing 
            }

    });

  });
</script>
```

**Body-html elements-**

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<form name="main" method="post" action="#" id="main">
  <select name="currency-select">
    <option value="default" id="default">Currency</option> 
    <option value="a" id="a">U.S Dollars (USD)</option> 
    <option value="b" id="b">Euros (EUR)</option> 
    <option value="c" id="c">British Pounds (GBP)</option> 
  </select>
</form>

<form name="child" id="child" method="post" action="#">
  <select name="currency-child" id="child1">
  </select>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: @tlt2w when you hide and show the elements, control of this elements will be some complicated, but when you append a new element to the page, other server side languages have a certain behavior and projected with this elements too...<br>I hope you find it helpful...

Comment: Thanks @Kiyarash! I'll look into it and modify the code I have right now to match your suggestions.

Comment: @tlt2w You're welcome... I tested the code and works fine.
Just be careful to add the jQuery file to your page with correct address...